# Apache configuration: randomly adds a sub folder to a path

Tags: php, apache, navigation, http-status-code-404

I have a problem.

I ma moving a system from one server to another and I came across a peculiar problem. There are some pages placed in a subfolder like these:

xttp://test.domain.com/admin/oders.php

xttp://test.domain.com/admin/users.php

xttp://test.domain.com/admin/whatever.php

Now, when I move around the pages, via some simple menu with links I get most of the times correct hits. But from time to time I end up on say:

xttp://test.domain.com/admin/admin/oders.php - which obviously causes 404

When I go back to previous page and press the link again it again works all right. Also when I hover over the links they always show proper paths regardless of whether I am going to get 404 or not. All links are dynamically generated by the scripts but they work perfectly on old server and as I say to a naked eye it all looks OK, right until I press the link.

Anyone has an idea where to look for a bug or which tool to use to see what is happening when I press the link? URL mod rewrite? Domain configuration? I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the scripts are getting confused between

- [xttp://test.domain.com]/admin/file.php
- admin/file.php
- file.php

Without seeing how the URLs are generated it's impossible to say how this is happening.

Comment: Very true. I didn't realized that there were some javascript functions to actually handle links and those were broken. This seems to be a very system specific issue and not connected with any sort of Apache configuration. Thanks for you answer though.